# How to leave a Collective?

Tags: support, collectives

I joined a Collective just to have a look around, but now I want to leave it. Is there a way to do so, and if so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you open the Collective, you should see two buttons at the top right; <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> and <kbd>Joined</kbd>:

[image]

When you hover over the "Joined" button, its text changes to become "Leave". Simply click on the "Leave" button and you should be good to go:

[image]

Note that you can also do the same thing on the [Collectives page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives):

[image]

Comment: That's... weird UX. A button that only says what it's gonna do when you hover over it? I wonder how that works on touchscreen devices.

Comment: It can't be hovered. I've submitted [a FR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408976/make-the-leave-collective-button-say-so-without-the-need-to-hover-it) to change that.

Comment: When it's joined it *should* just *say* "Leave"... shouldn't require hovering around. That's not "weird" UX, it is *bad* UX.

Comment: I agree. Hopefully, @Cerbrus's feature request is picked up soon. I will then update the answer. Note that a [similar request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345676/348196) was made when the Follow feature was announced but it got declined. IMO, it's even worse with "Follow/Following" because the text doesn't even change on hover.