# Make the "Leave collective" button say so without the need to hover it

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, user-interface, user-experience, collectives

Inspired from this question:

[How to leave a Collective?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408972/how-to-leave-a-collective)

The [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408973/1835379) there exposes some (imo) bad UX:

> When you open the Collective, you should see two buttons at the top right; <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> and <kbd>Joined</kbd>:
>
> [image]
>
> When you hover over the "Joined" button, its text changes to become "Leave". Simply click on the "Leave" button and you should be good to go:
>
> [image]

This means that button only shows what it's gonna do *when you hover over it.*
(On top of that, it changes size & color)

Considering it's impossible to hover over anything on mobile devices, users will just have to guess that <kbd>Joined</kbd> means <kbd>Leave</kbd>.

I'd like to request for this button to be simplified.

Comment: Sorry, once Borg takes you, there is no leaving ;)

Comment: _"Gooble, gobble, we accept her, we accept her, one of us, one of us!"_

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar would you say that Resistance (to Collectives) Is Futile? :p

Comment: @VLAZ I most certainly would, does not mean it is not worth trying ;P ... and, yes I can see the future... and Collectives will fail... https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/313443/resistance-is-futile

Comment: "subscribe" -> "unsubscribe". So, so common. But of course that is not hip enough.

Comment: @Gimby wait, you think users have the brain capacity to realize that if the action says "leave", they are currently a member? :) Seems like it's too much to expect these days. /s

Comment: @OlegValter if it works for Youtube and Twitch... On Twitch I believe they call it "follow -> unfollow" which might be better suited.

Comment: @Gimby - yeah, well, I meant the above to be in agreement with making this a switch (join/leave; follow/unfollow, etc); don't understand why someone thought it is a good idea to have 3 states (reminds me of the "True, False, FileNotFound" joke).

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't necessary to hover over the button to see that it would let me leave the Collective, I wouldn't have needed to ask how to leave a Collective.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

We understand and recognize the frustration around the usability of this feature. However, we don’t feel that the correct solution is clear. The impact of this is also relatively small, so for that reason, we don’t foresee it being prioritized on its own any time soon. We might be taking more time to give this feature the proper exploration and research as a part of some bigger initiative in the future, but also don’t have any conclusive plans on when/whether that might happen. As such, we are tagging the request [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now and keeping track of it in our backlog.

Comment: Thank you for your update.
Obviously, this isn't _exactly_ what I hoped for, but it's good to know that the issue is recognized and registered.

Comment: I'm disappointed this is getting so heavily downvoted. We want communication, and when we get it, we "dislike" it. This is not a major issue, so it's really not a problem that it's not a high priority fix.

Comment: @cerbrus I think the downvotes are for the fact that they're giving this such a low priority. It's a bad UX, and people don't like bad UX. (I was actually going to downvote it myself for that very reason until I read your comment.)

Comment: @Cerbrus - I did not want to initially, but ended up downvoting after some deliberation. Although it is nice that we have the response, and the reasoning is definitely understandable, the whole feature wad shoved down our throats and is gleefully pitched as a success by marketing, whilst we can't even have small things like unintuitive button behaviour prioritized higher than "maybe, not likely, maybe sometime, maybe never. Noted". It is the bigger picture of the whole thing that makes me (and probably others) sad to hear that it will not be addressed anytime soon.